# How to save a comment to database under the name "Anonymous"?

Tags: php, mysql

There is following PHP code for the guestbook:

```
<?php require_once('config.php');

if(!empty($_POST['comment'])) {
    $stmt = $dbConn->prepare('INSERT INTO comments(`author`, `comment`) VALUES(:author, :comment)');
    $stmt->execute(array('author' => $_POST['author'], 'comment' => $_POST['comment']));
    header("location: /index.php");
}

$stmt = $dbConn->prepare('SELECT author, comment, created_at FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC');
$stmt->execute();
$comments = $stmt->fetchAll();
;?>

<title>Comments Page</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>

<div id='comments-header'>
    <h1></h1>
</div>
<div id='comments-form'>
    <h3>Please add your comment</h3>
    <form method='post'>
        <div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="author" placeholder="Enter your name">
            </div>
            <div>
                <textarea name='comment' placeholder="Enter your comment"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <br>
                <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Save'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div id='comments-panel'>
    <h3>Comments:</h3>
    <?php foreach ($comments as $comment): ?>
        <p><?=$comment['comment']?>
            <span class='comment-date comment-author'>
                (<?=$comment['author']?> <?=$comment['created_at'];?>)
            </span>
        </p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

The code is almost ready, but I have a question.

According to problem specification, if user didn't indicate his name, we need to save his comment to database under the name "Anonymous". How to implement it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Test if user value is empty, if yes, replace it by anonymous. Dead simple

Comment: `$author = !empty($_POST['author']) ? $_POST['author'] :  "Anonymous";`

Comment: @splash58 missing the h

Comment: @JulesR Yes! Thx :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 if(!empty($_POST['comment'])) {
   /* this is used to check whether author variable is empty or not*/
    $author = (!empty($_POST['author'])) ? trim($_POST['author']) : 'Anonymous';
    $stmt = $dbConn->prepare('INSERT INTO comments(`author`, `comment`) VALUES(:author, :comment)');
    $stmt->execute(array('author' => $author , 'comment' => $_POST['comment']));
    header("location: /index.php");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use an if.

```
if (!empty($_POST["author"]))
    $author = $_POST["author"]);
else
    $author = "Anon";
```

Or a ternary expression that will provide the same :

```
$author = ((!empty($_POST["author"])) ? ($_POST["author"]) : ("Anon"));
```

If you're using php 7, you can use this, which provide the same :

```
$author = ((!empty($_POST["author"])) ?? ("Anon"));
```

And then in your parameters : `$stmt->execute(array('author' => $author ...`

Note that you don't need to wrap parenthesis around every elements of the ternary expression. That's an old habit I have.

Answer (score 3):

Simply check if the author has been set in the POST array and if not set it to a default value using a ternary operator, and change the variable in the execute parameter array.

```
<?php require_once('config.php');

$auth = isset($_POST['author']) ? $_POST['author'] : 'ANON';

if(!empty($_POST['comment'])) {
    $stmt = $dbConn->prepare('INSERT INTO comments(`author`, `comment`) VALUES(:author, :comment)');
    $stmt->execute(array('author' => $auth, 'comment' => $_POST['comment']));
    // changed                       ^^^^^
    header("location: /index.php");
}

$stmt = $dbConn->prepare('SELECT author, comment, created_at FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC');
$stmt->execute();
$comments = $stmt->fetchAll();
;?>

<title>Comments Page</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>

<div id='comments-header'>
    <h1></h1>
</div>
<div id='comments-form'>
    <h3>Please add your comment</h3>
    <form method='post'>
        <div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="author" placeholder="Enter your name">
            </div>
            <div>
                <textarea name='comment' placeholder="Enter your comment"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div>
                <br>
                <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Save'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div id='comments-panel'>
    <h3>Comments:</h3>
    <?php foreach ($comments as $comment): ?>
        <p><?=$comment['comment']?>
            <span class='comment-date comment-author'>
                (<?=$comment['author']?> <?=$comment['created_at'];?>)
            </span>
        </p>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```